# Qatar's "travel with confidence" and travel in January

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, qatar-airways, qatar

I'm planning on buying a return ticket departing in November and returning in January.

I am uncertain if I will be able to return at the expected date due to possible travel restrictions etc.

Qatar's [travel with confidence](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/travel-with-confidence.html) policy says I may "change your travel date or destination free of charge, as often as you need, for travel until 31 December 2020".

Does it make sense to book a ticket returning in December instead and changing the booking later? I have been unable to get through to Qatar's call center.

Comment: I don’t understand your question

Comment: @Traveller Updated the question to include more information about the "Travel with Confidence" program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to carefully read the terms and conditions at the bottom of the page you have linked. There are a few potential caveats.

> Valid for travel on/before 31 December 2020.

I would interpret this as you can change the outbound but not the return flight if it's in Jan 2021

> Rerouting for voluntary purposes (i.e. where there has been no flight disruption) is possible 14 (fourteen) days after making the booking.

This sounds like you can only reroute 14 days after booking. It's unclear whether something like "I'm not allowed to enter my destination country" would count as "voluntary purpose" or "flight disruption". It's also not clear whether this 14-day limit is only for changes to the actual routing (locations) or also applies to date changes.

> New flights must be booked in the same booking class (RBD), ... If the same booking class is not available, a fare and taxes difference may apply.

That means: if the same fare is not available for your new dates or routing, you may have to pay a hefty fee. Prices are currently very low but chances are they will rise rapidly when travel resumes.

Answer (score 3):

The [Travel with Confidence](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/travel-with-confidence.html) terms permit a free-of-charge change of travel dates, but only for flights before December 31, 2020. Qatar's text says:

> You can change your travel date or destination free of charge, as often as you need, for travel until 31 December 2020.

Because your proposed return flight is in January 2021, the policy won't apply.

Any change of a January 2021 return flight will presumably incur a change fee, unless Qatar's policy changes.